# No sound in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, 18.04, pulseaudio, alsa

When I first installed it there was sound but after doing updates, upgrades, installations and couple of restarts the sound is gone.

I ran this codes -

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Then restarted but no luck.

Then I tried,

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

But still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to get back the sound.

I ran this code -

```
pactl load-module module-detect
```

and got

> 21

Now the sound is back.

The problem was it was not detecting any **Hardware Output Devices**

Comment: I had the same problem, and ran the pactl command and I get a response of "28", and the sound comes back on,,,   Settings shows "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" as the Sound Output Device...   Everything is fine, until I shutdown my laptop and restart, then it is back to no sound, and "Dummy Output" for the Sound Output Device...  ...

Comment: @MattB Update your kernel with Ukuu.

Here's how to install it - 

Open up your terminal and copy and paste the codes - 
`sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install ukuu`

Then install latest kernel and restart.

I hope it will solve the problem.

Comment: So doing the upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 doesn't update the kernel?    Everything worked fine in 16.04

Comment: Will it be obvious which version of the kernel I should install I'm assuming the most recent stable version?

Comment: I used ukuu to update my kernel, but still no sound...   When I restart I still have "Dummy Output" for the audio output, and have to run "pactl load-module module-detect" to get "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo".....

Comment: For anyone who is here after upgrading to 20.04 - I had the same issue with Dell XPS 9560 after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04. Nothing helped except `sudo alsa force-reload` after each reboot. `pactl load-module module-detect` looks to have helped fix this issue permanently now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the output options at sound settings?

After having updated my hardware (graphic card with built-in sound module) the setting had changed without notice. Also there were two different HDMI devices listed. Only one of them was working.

Comment: I have only dummy output in there.

Answer (score 1):

I am using ubuntu 18.04. In my case, Audio suddenly stopped working. Tried a bunch of hacks shared by other users but no luck. But the following command worked instantly:

```
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*
```

Comment: It's better if you update the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

for me I removed google-chrome-remote-desktop and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If on (k)ubuntu 18.04 and other answers fails

**and if** `sudo alsa force-reload` says *no modules were loaded*, try this:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

and then reboot. The kernel update script had a problem in some kernels around version 4.15.0-... Supposedly, it was fixed from kernel version 4.15.0-109 onward, but in my case 4.15.0-109 and 4.15.0-111 caused another problem, with expanding kernel and system logs till my disk was full. The above works best and gets you to the newest kernel supported for 18.04 LTS (there are similar packages for other LTS versions).